# Canvas rotation effect of x and y

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have gotten the effect before where I could make an image move in the direction it was facing. but now when i try, the image rotates, but doesn't move in the right direction.
How do I make an image in canvas move in the direction it's facing?

My code:

```
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(bulletArray[i].x, bulletArray[i].y);
    ctx.rotate(bulletArray[i].degree);
    ctx.translate(-bulletArray[i].x, -bulletArray[i].y);
    bulletArray[i].x++;
    ctx.drawImage(bullet, bulletArray[i].x, bulletArray[i].y, 10, 10);
    ctx.restore();
```

(this is in a game loop so it repeats)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. the reason it was not rotating is because the rotation point need to be the center of the screen and not the bullet. this will make the bullet move correctly instead of just spinning.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want a rotation, then don't use

```
ctx.rotate(bulletArray[i].degree);
```

in your code

Comment: I do want a rotation. what i want to know is why the bullet does not move in the direction of the rotation. (btw) i am able to do this on other things so something about this arrangement of code in particular is whats wrong.

Comment: Then use `sin` and `cos` functions to calculate the right angle for moving. Attention: the angle is not in degree, but in radiant!

Comment: I already figured it out and have posted the answer. also, the degree property is converted into radians.